# Preg_match validating special chars inside a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, sanitization

I want to only allow letters, numbers, spaces, unserscore and hyphens.

So far i thought that this preg_match would do the job:

```
if(preg_match('/[^a-z0-9 _]+$/i', $name)) {
$error = "Name may only contain letters, numbers, spaces, \"_\" and \"-\".";
}
```

But i just realized that special chars inside a string, would not generate an error. For example

> hello"@£$joe

would not generate an error. Is it possible to make a little change and make it work, or do i need another solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the `$` symbol. You are specifically asking it to match the end of string. The expression `/[^a-z0-9 _]+$/i` will not match `hello"@£$joe` because `joe` matches `[a-z0-9 _]+$`; so it obviously won't match when you negate the class. Remove the `$` symbol and everything will be as expected:

```
if(preg_match('/[^a-z0-9 _]+/i', $name)) {
// preg_match will return true if it finds 
// a character *other than* a-z, 0-9, space and _
// *anywhere* inside the string
}
```

Test it in your browser by pasting these lines one by one in the JavaScript console:

```js
/[^a-z0-9 _]+/i.test("@hello");        // true
/[^a-z0-9 _]+/i.test("joe@");          // true
/[^a-z0-9 _]+/i.test("hello\"@£$joe"); // true
/[^a-z0-9 _]+/i.test("hello joe");     // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bring the `^` outside the character class:

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-z0-9 _]+$/i', $name)) {
```

A `^` inside (at the beginning) a character class acts like a character class negator.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]| |_|-)+$/
```

use this regular expression

Comment: Why not put everything in one class? `[-_ a-zA-Z0-9]`

Answer (score 0):

Here Take this:

```
/^[a-z0-9\s\-_]+$/i
```

this expression is tested by me with dummy data.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
function valueanalysis(form){
    var vals = form.vals.value;

    alert(/^[a-z0-9\s\-_]+$/i.test(vals));

    return false;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form onsubmit="return valueanalysis(this);">
<input type="text" name="vals"/>
<input type="submit" value="Check" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

use this code in a html file check the validation by filling the value and press enter afterwards to check if true or not.

**Note:-**   regular expressions are same for all languages.

```
<?php


if(preg_match("/^[a-z0-9\s\-_]+$/i","ASDhello-dasd  asddasd_dsad")){
    echo "true";
}
else{
    echo "false";
}
?>
```

Comment: may be you r doing some thing wrong it is working fine in my case. each and every value is working properly take this edit in the answer

Comment: Hmm, yea it works when i test your code. But when using PHP this does now work: `if(preg_match('/^[a-z0-9\s\-_]+$/i', $name)) {
$error = "Name may only contain letters, numbers, spaces, \"_\" and \"-\".";
}`

Comment: Try the new php code this also gives the correct thing see the edit

Comment: I think it will work if $ is removed like Salman A's solution. Thank for your time VIPIN